# C++: How to make a object (class) with two brackets. for ex Point obj1((2,2),(3,8))

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
class Point
{
private:
    float x,y;
public:
    Point(const float _x,const float _y)
    {
        x=_x;
        y=_y;
    }
    ~Point(){};
};

class triangle
{
private:
    Point *objPOA;
    Point *objPOB;
    Point *objPOC;
public:
    triangle(const float a,const float b,const float c,const float d,const float e,const float f)
    {
        objPOA=new Point(a,b);
        objPOB=new Point(c,d);
        objPOC=new Point(e,f);

    }
    ~triangle()
    {
        delete objPOA;
        delete objPOB;
        delete objPOC;
    }
};
```

I want to make this

```
int main()
{
    triangle obj((1,2),(2,5),(8,6));
    return 0;
}
```

It can be done;
I mean inside obj parameters include brackets.

This can be done without brackets but i want to know if it is possible with brackets.

Comment: No, it's not possible, because an expression like `Point(1,2)` cannot automatically deduced from `(1,2)`. Curly brackets may work perhaps: `triangle obj({1,2},{2,5},{8,6});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your triangle constructor take 3 `Point`s

```
triangle(const Point& p1, const Point& p2, const Point& p3): 
    objPOA(p1), objPOB(p2), objPOC(p3) {}
```

and instead of pointers define in your class regular objects of type `Point`

```
Point objPOA, objPOB, objPOC;
```

You can then use the `{ }` to initialize `Point`s in the constructor of the `triangle` as

```
triangle obj({1,2},{2,5},{8,6});
```

because `Point` is an aggregate. In C++11 the above syntax is valid even if `Point` is a non-aggregate, due to the new [uniform initialization syntax](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/133688/144548).